# React Native Firebase; undefined is not an object ('evaluating childsnapshot.val().date.substring')?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

So when I first load up my application the "load_pins()" function I made works fine. (the others are supposed to say undefined right now because I did not code them in yet)

[image]

Here is the code for that function:

```
  load_pins(){


var database = firebase.database(firebaseApp);
var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('posts');

this.setState({
  markers: []
});

commentsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)  {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val().latitude+'end');
    console.log(childSnapshot.val().longitude+'end');

    var lat = parseFloat(childSnapshot.val().latitude.trim());
    var lng = parseFloat(childSnapshot.val().longitude.trim());

    var icon_link;
    if(childSnapshot.val().sport == 'key0'){
      icon_link = 'http://i.imgur.com/TtnXPRv.png';
    }
    if(childSnapshot.val().sport == 'key1'){
      icon_link = 'http://i.imgur.com/DemGBtm.png';
    }
    if(childSnapshot.val().sport == 'key2'){
      icon_link = 'http://i.imgur.com/mo7lA6q.png';
    }
    if(childSnapshot.val().sport == 'key3'){
      icon_link = 'http://i.imgur.com/0ZmMQud.png';
    }
    if(childSnapshot.val().sport == 'key4'){
      icon_link = 'http://i.imgur.com/h044WXU.png';
    }

    this.setState((prevState) =>{
      return{
      markers: [...prevState.markers,
        //...this.state.markers,
        {
          coordinate: {
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: lng,
          },
          key: id++,
          color: 'red',
          image: icon_link,
          title: childSnapshot.val().date.substring(0,10),
          description: 'test description'
        },
      ]
      }
    });

  }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));

  }
```

However when I call the function again right after updating the firebase database with a new pin I get the error.

[image]

When I refresh the app the new pin appears as correctly with the date and everything. Without .substring(0,10) it doesnt crash but I get "undefined" for the callout for the pin. If the database wasn't updating fast enough then I would assume childsnapshot.val().sport would not work either but it works.

Any insight on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if the code is really bad i'm brand new to databases and javascript type programming.

Firebase Database:

[image]

If I include console.log(childsnapshot.val()) at the beginning of the loop.

```
09-12 19:29:04.723  3129  3786 I ReactNativeJS: { contact_information: 'NA',
09-12 19:29:04.723  3129  3786 I ReactNativeJS:   end_time: '20:00',
09-12 19:29:04.723  3129  3786 I ReactNativeJS:   extra_information: 'NA',
09-12 19:29:04.723  3129  3786 I ReactNativeJS:   latitude: '38.414',
09-12 19:29:04.723  3129  3786 I ReactNativeJS:   longitude: '-75.56',
09-12 19:29:04.723  3129  3786 I ReactNativeJS:   sport: 'key0',
09-12 19:29:04.723  3129  3786 I ReactNativeJS:   start_time: '20:00' }
```

However this is what the database says for that entry (the date is there):
[image]

Comment: That's really odd. Can you add a `console.log(childsnapshot.val())` and update your question with it's return please?

Comment: Actually I found out if I take out .substring(0,10) the error no longer appears. Any idea why that is? Also I updated the question with the return.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm still not sure, so I will post my thoughts and let's try to find out what can be, ok? You said when you `console.log` the `data` doesn't appear, but it does in your schema. Would you mind just confirm this is really happening, please? Keep your firebase console window opened in half screen and your app in the other half, when you add a new item just pay attention if the `data` is being set and in how many times firebase triggers any change (green or yellou feedback). Then reload your app and check if any changes happened in firebase console. Let me know the results

Comment: When you take out `.substring()` the `date` appears or it returns empty?

Comment: Hi soutot, sorry for the late response. It triggers once with the full date in. However the log shows the entry without the date. Actually it returns empty without .substring so the issue is still there.

Comment: I think I found out: you are using this ref `var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('posts');` and the node that is opened in your print screen is `users-post`. So your ref should be  `var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('users-posts');`. Just make sure you are referring to the same node when you add and read data from Firebase. Let me know if it works.